# ios - How to get label value from table cell by click button in table cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an UITableView, in each cell it's have some label and a button. I want to get all label value when I click the button. How to do this? Thank you.

Comment: How does the value get into the label in the first place?

Comment: @PhillipMills The label value is come from another class

Comment: If you are familiar with the concept of delegation. This should be easy

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by closure or delegation

**1: Closure**

In your tableViewCell class create a variable like this

**customObject** is the object you passed the tableviewCell to load the data

```
var cellData: customObject? {

    didSet {
        // do your loding labels in here
    }
}

var clickHandler: ((customObject) -> Void)!
```

and inside of you action button add this

```
 @IBAction func replyAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if let customObject = customObject {
        clickHandler(customObject)
    }
}
```

now go to where are you deque the table

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! YourCustomCell

   // add this
   cell.clickHandler = { customObject in 

   print("myCell.customObject = \(customObject)")

   }
}
```

this will do the magic

**2. Delegation**

Create a delegate methode like this

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate {
    func getCustomObject(in cell: CustomCell, withCustomObject object: CustomObject)
}
```

now in your cell class add delegate variable

```
 var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?
```

and inside of you action button add this

```
@IBAction func replyAction(_ sender: Any) {
    if let customObject = customObject {
        delegate.getCustomObject(in: self, withCustomObject: customObject)
    }
}
```

and now for the last part go to class you implemented the table view and this to where it shows

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { 
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! YourCustomCell

   // add this
   cell.delegate = self
}
```

and inside of class you should add you delegate method

```
extension YourClass: CustomCellDelegate {

    getCustomObject(in cell: CustomCell, withCustomObject object: CustomObject) {
         print("current cell data = \(CustomObject)"
    }

}
```

this will do the job too

Hop this will Helps

Answer (score 0):

Create `IBAction` method for the button inside the cell custom class and inside it print

```
   print("label text : \(self.lbl.text)")
```

Or use delegate to send that value to the VC the contains the tableView

Answer (score 0):

First of all. You should have a model object which you are using it to load the values of label. Use

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {}
```

to get the index then try getting the value from the model using the index
for example you have an array `myArray` then you could access the value using `myArray[indexPath.row]` to get the value. Then save, pass and use it where ever you want. Then implement a delegate method in your custom table cell class passing the indexPath. Then refresh the cell using `tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(item:0,section:0)], with: .fade)`